# which port uses the rethinkdb client driver? How to set a specific port to listen the rethinkdb client driver?

Tags: rethinkdb

I have a client host and a different rethinkdb server host. I need to set the firewall rules among this servers related to the rethinkdb client driver. I already know that the rethinkdb server should accept tcp connections in port 28015, but I don't know which local port uses the client driver in the client host to request data and to receive data from the rethinkdb server. So my question is which port use the rethinkdb client driver for request data and for receive data from the rethinkdb server host ? In case the client driver uses random ports, how can I set the client driver to use a specific port to request and to receive data from the rethinkdb server?

Comment: The local outgoing port on the client cannot be set (at least not with the official drivers). It is automatically assigned by the operating system.
Note that the client never listens to any incoming connections though. If your firewall is stateful, you shouldn't need to allow any incoming TCP connections to the client, since the client will always establish TCP connections with the server's port 28015. Never the other way around.

Comment: Thank you, now is clear for me, you made me note that the client never listens to any incoming connections and my firewall is stateful,so as you said, since the client will always stablish TCP connections,  packets matching a known active connection (previously set by the client driver) will be allowed by a stateful firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Daniel Mewes said:

> The local outgoing port on the client cannot be set (at least not with
>   the official drivers). It is automatically assigned by the operating
>   system. Note that the client never listens to any incoming connections
>   though.

Can you mark this as answered @nerva13?